# Accessing any string type element inserted within multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Suppose I have an array:

```
let x = [[["3"]]];
```

I can access easily to the inserted element without using object notation by simply writing

```
parseInt(x); // 3
```

But if we

```
let x = [[["a"]]];
```

There is no number within multiple arrays in x, so how can we access ("a") directly in one step, like `parseInt()` for above situation. Is there any way, then suggest?

Comment: `x.flat(Infinity)[0]`? Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212) and use the available static and instance methods of [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `toString` function for that

```js
console.log([[["a"]]].toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x[0]=[["a"]]

x[0][0]=["a"]
```

So you want

```
x[0][0][0]
```